# "I thought I flushed that in toilet" vs "I thought I flush that in toilet" - which is right?

Tags: grammaticality, past-tense

Consider these two sentences:

> "I thought I flushed that in toilet."

and:

> "I thought I flush that in toilet."

Is this appropriate to use "thought" with "flushed"? Both are past tenses.

Comment: Why do you think it would be inappropriate?

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. It would help to [edit] your post to explain the situation you are trying to describe. Neither sentence as you have provided them is idiomatic; theoretically, either *I thought I flushed that down the toilet* or *I thought I flush that down the toilet* could be correct,
 but they mean different things. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance on asking questions.

Comment: All singular, uncountable nouns in English **must have** a _determiner_ such as an article. There is only one _noun_ in your sentence. Do you know what it is?

Answer (score 3):

In this case,

> I *think* I flushed that down the toilet.

is pretty much the exact same as

> I *thought* I flushed that down the toilet.

These words/tenses are used in so many different contexts and with so many different intentions that it's too difficult to generalize on how to use them for all cases and still make an accurate statement. But @A.Galloway was correct; you should add "down".

Lastly, maybe some people will use the past tense (thought) to imply some kind of confidence, suggesting that at an earlier point in time they made a conscious effort to verify that "it" was flushed. Conversely, people may use the present tense (think) to purposely include uncertainty, as if it's their first time thinking about whether or not "it" was actually flushed or not.

Comment: To add to this, I think the implication with the past tense is that something occurred to challenge the speaker's belief that the action occurred. Otherwise, they would simply assert "I flushed that down the toilet".

Answer (score 0):

When constructing a sentence in English, matching tenses are necessary to avoid grammatical errors. When you use the word "thought", that means you are using the **past** tense. That means that you need to conjugate all you other verbs the same way. In your case, you would need to use "thought" and "flushed". Remember, however, that you need a preposition and an article for the word "toilet". The correct sentence would be:

> I thought I flushed that *down the* toilet.

Comment: You're quite right that *grammatically* speaking your version is *correct = **error-free***. But there aren't that many contexts where it would be *correct = **appropriate*** (too coarse for many situations, and probably excessively belittling for many contexts where somewhat crude language might otherwise be acceptable).

Comment: I don't think your rationale (_matching tenses are necessary; you need to conjugate all you other verbs the same way_) always holds true. For example, there is nothing wrong with saying, "I think I flushed that down the toilet," (present/past) or, "I think I will flush that down the toilet" (present/future).

Comment: @J.R. Right, the sentence "I thought I would flush that down the toilet tomorrow, but I changed my mind" is grammatically fine, albeit somewhat strange.

Comment: @Andrew - Sure, that one is a little bit strange, but this one isn't: _I thought I would travel to New York next weekend, but I changed my mind._